# Insert a new set of headers in a df but preserve the existing headers and set them to the first row of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Looking to amend a df:

```
Test_Data = [
                ('Client', ['A','B','C']),
                ('2018-11', [10,20,30]),
                ('2018-12', [10, 20, 30]),
             ]

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Test_Data))
print(df)

  Client  2018-11  2018-12
0      A       10       10
1      B       20       20
2      C       30       30
```

Desired output:

```
Report_Mongo    Client  Month_1  Month_2
0               Client  2018-11  2018-12
1               A       10       10
2               B       20       20
3               C       30       30
```

So move existing headers down one row and insert the new headers:

```
c = ['Report_Mongo','client', 'Month_1', 'Month_2']
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56286649/4909087)?

Comment: Hi @cs95, need first row by columns not the multiindex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest create `MultiIndex` for not mixing numeric with strings data in DataFrame:

```
c = ['Report_Mongo','client', 'Month_1', 'Month_2']

#get columns by list without first element
df.columns = [c[1:], df.columns]
#get first element to names of columns
df.columns.names = (c[0], '')
print(df)

Report_Mongo client Month_1 Month_2
             Client 2018-11 2018-12
0                 A      10      10
1                 B      20      20
2                 C      30      30
```

If need first row by columns it is possible with `append`, but most preferable is first solution:

```
c = ['Report_Mongo','client', 'Month_1', 'Month_2']

df = df.columns.to_frame().T.append(df, ignore_index=True)
df.columns = c[1:]
df.columns.name = c[0]
print(df)

Report_Mongo  client  Month_1  Month_2
0             Client  2018-11  2018-12
1                  A       10       10
2                  B       20       20
3                  C       30       30
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. Wierd request but it fits in with some crazy Django legacy code.